# WordPress: Show all posts from specific category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I Need to show latest post from a specified category in WordPress.

The category is " News World ", and I am try this code but show me all post from all category.

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'paged' => $paged
            ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=9'); //your category id 
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

    //loop items go here

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'category_name' => 'News World' 
        ) );
```

As per [this reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters). Note that you should NOT use the category name. You need the category SLUG. So make sure your category News World has slug "News World".